# How to find complete QuantumOperator() Matrix

Tags: quantum-computing

I am defining a quantum operator as

`X1 = QuantumOperator["PauliX", {3}]`

This operator is expected to act on qubit 3 and so supposed to be 8x8 matrix.

But when I perform

```
X1["Matrix"] // MatrixForm
```

I get 2x2 matrix as below

[image]

Can someone help me get the complete matrix from Mathematica QuantumOperator()?

I can use tensor products but on a bigger system, I would prefer to track only the Pauli matrices (for my Ising model) on Mathematica built-in functions and not track tensoring the identity matrices.

Update:
Link to Mathematica [QuantumOperator](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/wolframquantumframework/DeployedResources/Paclet/Wolfram/QuantumFramework/Documentation/ref/QuantumOperator.html) function - https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/wolframquantumframework/DeployedResources/Paclet/Wolfram/QuantumFramework/Documentation/ref/QuantumOperator.html

Comment: Please include a link to the documentation of the function `QuantumOperator` that you are using here, I did not find it in [the documentation center](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=QuantumOperator).

Comment: The link is https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/wolframquantumframework/DeployedResources/Paclet/Wolfram/QuantumFramework/Documentation/ref/QuantumOperator.html Added the link in original; question

Comment: Thank you. So to run this, one needs `PacletInstall["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"]` followed by ``Needs["Wolfram`QuantumFramework`"]``.

Comment: Yes! That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuantumOperator tries not to expand tensors until it is necessary for composition.
One way to get the expanded matrix is to order the operator first:

```
QuantumOperator["H", {3}]["Ordered", 1, 3]["Matrix"]
```

**EDIT**:

I just have added an update so that this also works:

```
QuantumOperator["CX"]["Ordered", 1, 3]
```

Before, it worked only if you specify a basis:

```
QuantumOperator["CX" -> {1, 3}]["OrderedInput", Range[3], QuditBasis[2, 3]]

QuantumOperator["CX" -> {1, 3}]["OrderedOutput", Range[3], QuditBasis[2, 3]]
```

Now it assumes a usual computational qubit basis for missing qudits, so this should work too:

```
QuantumOperator["CX" -> {3, 1}, {"X", "Y"}]["Ordered", 1, 4]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for all kind of gates like CX  gate. An example is QuantumOperator["CX"]["Ordered", 1, 3]["Matrix"] // MatrixForm . This gives an error "QuantumOperator::undefprop: property Ordered is undefined for this state"

Comment: @user1847424 See edit.